# MSSQL: DISTINCT that takes date-ranges into consideration

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have a table that looks more less like that:

```
 K_PKEY          D_FROM               D_TO                 PERC
============ ==================== ==================== ===========
0013         01-JAN-2009 00:00:00 31-JUL-2011 00:00:00
0013         01-AUG-2011 00:00:00 31-DEC-2011 00:00:00
0013         01-JAN-2012 00:00:00 31-MAR-2012 00:00:00
0013         01-APR-2012 00:00:00 31-DEC-2012 00:00:00   75.000000
0013         01-JAN-2013 00:00:00 31-JAN-2013 00:00:00   50.000000
0013         01-FEB-2013 00:00:00 28-FEB-2013 00:00:00   50.000000
0013         01-MAR-2013 00:00:00 31-AUG-2013 00:00:00   75.000000
0013         01-SEP-2013 00:00:00 31-MAY-2015 00:00:00   75.000000
0013         01-JUN-2015 00:00:00 31-DEC-2100 00:00:00
```

I'm trying to build a DISTICT query that takes specific date ranges into consideration.

This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT k_pkey, MIN(d_from), MAX(d_to), perc FROM my_table GROUP BY k_pkey
```

It doesn't work the way I want and I understand why. 
MIN() and MAX() combined with DISTINCT work globally, which is natural for that type of query. This results in:

```
K_PKEY           D_FROM               D_TO                 PERC
============ ==================== ==================== ===========
0013         01-JAN-2009 00:00:00 31-DEC-2100 00:00:00
0013         01-APR-2012 00:00:00 31-MAY-2015 00:00:00   75.000000
0013         01-JAN-2013 00:00:00 28-FEB-2013 00:00:00   50.000000
```

What I want to achieve is to keep chronological order and combine only ranges that are (so to say) next to each other.

```
K_PKEY           D_FROM               D_TO                 PERC
============ ==================== ==================== ===========
0013         01-JAN-2009 00:00:00 31-MAR-2012 00:00:00
0013         01-APR-2012 00:00:00 31-DEC-2012 00:00:00   75.000000
0013         01-JAN-2013 00:00:00 28-FEB-2013 00:00:00   50.000000
0013         01-MAR-2013 00:00:00 31-MAY-2015 00:00:00   75.000000
0013         01-JUN-2015 00:00:00 31-DEC-2100 00:00:00
```

Is it possible with one sql query (i don't want to use sql procedure if possible)? Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? Depending on this you might have a look on window functions (OVER clause). But I doubt, that I really understood your grouping criteria...

Comment: I would probably use a cursor to clean up the data and insert the cleaned data into a temp table. I would start with the first record and store its start and end date. I would then loop through the dataset and modify the start and end date as I look for ranges that lie next to one another. Finally I would just do a select distinct on what's left in my temp table.

Comment: Hi, I'm using MSSQL 2012

Comment: @Jesse Petronio yep, it doable this way, but I'm pretty desperate to make it in one query (bacause of serveral reasons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to combine adjacent rows together, based on the date and on `PERC` being the same.  The idea is to use a `left join` to determine which values start a new range.  Then, use a cumulative sum to count the number of starts up to each row.  This latter value can be used for grouping.

In SQL Server 2012+, the cumulative sum can be done directly.  In earlier versions, you would use `outer apply`.

The resulting query looks like this:

```
select k_pkey, min(d_from) as d_from, max(d_to) as d_to, perc
from (select t.*,
             sum(IsGroupStart) over (partition by k_pkey, perc order by d_from) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when t_prev.k_pkey is null then 1 else 0 end) as IsGroupStart
            from t left join
                 t tprev
                 on tprev.k_pkey = t.k_pkey and
                    (tprev.perc = t.perc or tprev.perc is null and t.perc is null) and
                    tprev.d_to = dateadd(day, -1, t.d_from)
           ) t
      ) t
group by grp, k_pkey, perc;
```

Comment: Nice! really nice! ;) @Gordon what do you think about use `LAG()` to find when a new group begins? `(case when isnull((lag(e.perc) OVER (order by d_from)),-1) <> e.perc then 1 else 0 end) as NewGroup`

Comment: Thank you - I'll check this soon and come back with feedback, but it seems to be exactly what I need :)

Comment: @DavidIsla . . . `LAG()` is a reasonable alternative instead of the self-join.